# WCF Rest Service with Cross Platform(PCL)

Tags: mono, xamarin.android, monodevelop

I apologize if this question asked before. I am still trying and not able to understand how to work with Cross Platform (PCL)support. We are developing an application to support iOS, Android and Windows Phone devices. We need to use same set of code (services,view-model and model) for all the above mentioned devices.

We need to use JSON data returned from Rest service.

Kindly provide us sample projects that call REST services with serialization using shared code which will work across different platforms(iOS,Android & Windows Phone)

Answer (score 0):

This page here, has some examples of exactly what you are looking for.

[PCL Link][1]

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CrossPlatformPortableClassLibrariesWithNETAreHappening.aspx

Comment: I have gone through the link but i didn't found sample cross platform application.  I am new to this Xamarin development. Kindly provide a simple sample application.